# Database block size and migration

Tags: postgresql

My client is planning to move their database from Oracle to PostgreSQL. Current blocksize is 32 KB for Oracle. As per Postgresql documentation and research on internet, 8k is default page size but can be increased to higher value if needed. so What issues should I expect when we migrate to PostgreSQL with a smaller block size?

Answer (score 2):

You might run into several problems, depending on what exactly is in the DB currently.  However, as the migration doesn't happen on the physical level, none of these problems will stem from the different page size.

Comment: Thanks! I am also trying to get the business logic of using 32k block size for the database. I am new on this project and was surprised to see such a large block size.